# ADODataSet deleting from joined table

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2009, ado, tadodataset

I have a Delphi app where I display a list of games that have been played from a query like this:

```
select  g.*, gt.id, gt.descr 
from GAMES g 
inner join game_types gt on gt.id = g.game_type
order by game_date DESC
```

When I click the delete button in the DBNavigator, the joined record from the game_types table is also deleted.  That's a problem because many other games can be of the same type.

What do I need to do to make it so that only the game is deleted but not the game type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the [Unique Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dynamic property

```
ADOQuery1.Properties['Unique Table'].Value := 'GAMES';
```

From the [MSDN ADO Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If the Unique Table dynamic property is set, and the Recordset is the
>   result of executing a JOIN operation on multiple tables, then the
>   Delete method will only delete rows from the table named in the Unique
>   Table property.

Comment: If you need to get really fancy with your updates, you can use the TUpdateSQL component and assign it to the UpdateObject of your query component.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set TADODataset's "Unique Table" property after opening your dataset.

```
ADODataset.Properties['Unique Table'].Value := 'GAMES';
```